# Is it possible to check the availability of external resources from the client side?

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

The idea of ​​the task is to give the user useful links for review.
But from the client side, at the ISP level, the resource can be blocked.

Is it possible, with javascript to check the availability of a foreign domain for the client?

The problem is in the cors policy, in fact the content of the resources is not even needed

Comment: You can try to load the favicon.ico

Comment: cors is also distributed on the favicon

Comment: You do not need cors: `const img = new Image(); img.onload=() => console.log('Site is available'); img.onerror=() => console.log('Site is not available'); img.src='https://somesite.com?favicon.ico?rdn' + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: rly, its work! thks!

Comment: What do you consider "available"? Should a 404 redirect be considered "available"? Because neither "no-cors" nor the ugly favicon trick wiil be able to tell you that.

Comment: @jabaa — `no-cors` is a statement that you don't want to do anything that requires permission from CORS. It is for requests that are entirely fire & forget. You can't check *anything* with that mode.

Comment: @Quentin I thought you can check the status code with `no-cors`. I guess, I remembered it wrong

Answer (score 0):

If the resource has a public image URL, you can "ping" it:

For example if they server their favicon themselves

```
const img = new Image(); 
img.onload=() => console.log('Site is available'); 
img.onerror=() => console.log('Site or favicon.ico is not available'); 
img.src='https://somesite.com?favicon.ico?rdn' + new Date().getTime(); // cache buster
```

Comment: Most websites use CDNs to serve their favicon, not all of the other ones have it as `favicon.ico`, and that would just tell that the server responsible to give that image was alive, not that the actual resource OP is interested in really is (could still be a 404, or 503 etc.